# force assertEquals(String s, Object o) to use o.toString()?

Tags: java, string, junit, tostring, assert

Is it possible to force

```
assertEquals("10,00 €", new Currency(bon.getTotal()))
```

to use the toString() method of the Currency Object?
(I don't want to call it myself.)

Since otherwise, it compares the references, which of course don't match.

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> expected: java.lang.String<10,00 €>
>
> but was: jam.cashregister.Currency<10,00 €>

**Update**

I finally ended up with this code:

```
assertEquals(new Currency(bon.getTotal()), "10,00 €");
```

> I don't know if it is a good idea to swap the expected with
>   the actual part, in the assertation.

```
public class Currency() {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this.toString().equals(other.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question JUnit's assertEquals method? If so you should add a JUnit tag.

Comment: Why don't you want to call toString yourself - what's the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: The only way is to override the `assertEquals` method.

Comment: But the best way is to convert "10,00 €"To a currency object and compare the two currecy objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compare two instances of `Currency`:

```
assertEquals(new Currency("10,00 €"), new Currency(bon.getTotal()))
```

Therefore, redefining `equals()` is mandatory. If the equality must be based on the string representation of `Currency`, it's also mandatory to override `toString()` (you probably already did that).

```
public class Currency {

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //overriden in a custom way
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other instanceof Currency) {
            Currency that = (Currency) other;
            return this.toString().equals(that.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: great, thanks. I totally forgot that Object has the equals method, used for comparing.  -.-

Comment: @jam Btw, I didn't mentionned it in my post, but it's a good practice to also override `hashCode()` everytime `equals()` is overriden (and vice-versa). :-)

Comment: @jam In order to properly work with Java collections. [More details here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the only way to do that is to write it yourself:

```
assertEquals("10,00 €", new Currency(bon.getTotal()).toString());
```

Comment: Laziness is one of the three virtues of a programmer! Do write your own `assertToStringEquals` helper if you find that you need this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I used this approach.
the  `assertEquals(20 ,   new Duller(result.multiple()).toString());` did not work.

```
public class MoneyTest {

    @Test
    public void testMultiplication(){
        Duller fiveValue= new Duller(5);
        Duller twoTimes = fiveValue.times(2);
        assertEquals(10,twoTimes.amount);

        Duller threeTimes = fiveValue.times(3);
        assertEquals(15, threeTimes.amount);

        Duller result = new Duller();
        result.setAmount(4);
        result.setTimes(5);
       int x=  result.multiple();


       /*
       org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
        Expected :20
        Actual   :com.bahar.test.domain.Duller@16aa0a0a
        */
      //  assertEquals(20 ,   new Duller(result.multiple(result.getTimes())); //actual and expected is obj
        assertEquals(20,x);
    }   
}


public class Duller {
    int amount;
    int times;

    public Duller(){}
    public Duller(int amount){
        this.amount=amount;
    }

     Duller times(int multiple){
     //   amount *=multiple; // version 1
        return new Duller(amount*multiple); //version 2
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getTimes() {
        return times;
    }

    public void setTimes(int times) {
        this.times = times;
    }
// changed the Dullar to int
   public int multiple(){
        //   amount *=multiple; // version 1
        return getAmount()*getTimes(); //version 2
       // return this.getAmount()*this.getTimes();

    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34998812)